# Python Text based game Error while debugging

Tags: python

I am working on a text-based game for a Python class I am taking. I keep running into the same error and I am not sure what it is that it's wanting me to do. I am sure it is something simple, but I am not understanding. Below is the code I have so far and the error I am getting. Any help is appreciated.

```
#Jessica Call


def showInstructions():
 print(
 "Stop The Shot Caller ======== COLLECT ALL ITEMS TO WIN. A Shot Caller is waiting for you! Just go South, go North, go East, go West. Collect Six items before you meet the Shot Caller.Find a Pistol, A key, Ammo, a Kevlar Vest, A Flashbang and the Evidence!")
def showStatus(currentRoom, inventory, rooms):
 print(' ---------------------------')
 print('You are in the ' + currentRoom)
 print('Inventory : ' + str(inventory))
 if "item" in rooms[currentRoom]:
  print('You see a ' + rooms[currentRoom]['item'])
def main():
 inventory = []
 rooms = {
 'Lobby': {'South': 'Basement','North': 'Study', 'East':
'Attic', 'West': 'Kitchen'},
 'Basement': {'North': 'Lobby', 'East': 'Security', 'item': 'Flashbang'},
 'Elevator': {'West': 'Study', 'item': 'Key'},
 'Study': {'South': 'Lobby', 'East': 'Elevator', 'item':
'Pistol'},
 'Kitchen': {'West': 'Lobby', 'item': 'Ammo'},
 'Attic': {'West': 'Lobby', 'North': 'Parking Lot', 'item': 'Kevlar Vest'},
 'Parking Lot': {'South': 'Attic', 'item': 'SHOT CALLER!!!!'},
 'Security': {'West': 'Basement', 'item': 'Evidence'}
 }
 currentRoom = 'IceHall'
 showInstructions()
 while True:
  showStatus(currentRoom, inventory, rooms)
 if "item" in rooms[currentRoom]:
  if rooms[currentRoom]['item'] == 'SHOT CALLER!!!!':
   print("DEAD!!!.... GAME OVER!")
 break
 if len(inventory) == 6:
  print("Congratulations! You have collected all items and now have won the game!")
 break
 print(" ---------------------------")
 print("Enter your move: ")
 move = ''
 while move == '':
  move = input('>')
  move = move.split()
  if len(move) != 2:
   print("Invalid Input!")
 continue
 if move[0] == 'go':
  if move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
   currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][move[1]]
 else:
  print("You can't go that way!")

 while move[0] == 'get':
  if "item" in rooms[currentRoom] and move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]['item']:
   inventory += [move[1]]
 print(move[1] + ' got!')
 del rooms[currentRoom]['item']
else:
  print("Can't get" + move[1] + "!")
 else:
 print("Invalid move!")
 print("You did it! You caught the Shot Caller!")
if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Error:
C:\Users\stoop\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/stoop/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py
File "C:\Users\stoop\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 58
else:
^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Check your indentation - `else` is unbounded (not in the function it seems you believe it should be under) and does not pair with any other `if` at the indentation level it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of the `else` in line 58 is wrong; it needs to be on the same level of indentation as the preceding `if`.

Comment: I've tried changing the indentation and still get an error

Comment: The problem is with the indentation of the else that precedes print("Can't get" + move[1] + "!"). That else has no preceding if to relate to. Simply moving the indentation of that else to that of the nearest preceding if won't help, since there are several unindented lines between that if and the else; so the Python interpreter assumes that the if block is over, and will give you an "unexpected indent" error when you move the indentation of the else to that of the if. You also need to adjust the indentations of the lines in between.